# ActiveMQ with ReplicatedLevelDB storage keeps file descriptors open for log files, so OS cannot free a space

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb

We are using a cluster of ActiveMQ 5.11.1 nodes (guarded by Zookeepers). Nodes use ReplicatedLevelDB storage. An application is able to produce and consume messages, but starting some time ago we've noticed a very weird issue.

It seems like ActiveMQ logs are deleted, but their FDs are opened (by ActiveMQ Java process) so Linux cannot clean those files. In the end we have a space leakage which is bad.

```
[root@server dirty.index#] lsof | grep -o "/home/.*" | grep deleted | sort | uniq
/home/activemq/activemq-data/000000126ecb3f49.log (deleted)
/home/activemq/activemq-data/00000012750b4590.log (deleted)
```

```
[root@server activemq-data#] lsof | grep -o "/home/.*" | grep deleted | wc -l
280
```

That happens only on the master node. After node restart, a new master is elected and all those files are removed. The new master has the same issue.

We've enabled `TRACE` log level for ActiveMQ - no luck, nothing suspicious (well, or we're missing something). Queues aren't big, 5-6 messages at max. All messages are consumed quickly. There are no obvious ERROR messages. APM also doesn't show anything suspicious

ReplicatedLevelDB config:

```xml
<persistenceAdapter>

    <replicatedLevelDB
      directory="activemq-data"
      replicas="5"
      bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61619"
      zkAddress="xx.xxx.xx.30:2181,xx.xxx.xx.31:2181,xx.xxx.xx.32:2181,xx.xxx.xx.33:2181,xx.xxx.xx.34:2181"
      zkPassword=""
      zkSessionTimeout="3s"
      zkPath="/xxx02"
      sync="quorum_mem"
      hostname="some.server"
      />

</persistenceAdapter>
```

No recent changes in ActiveMQ config.

We're stuck at the moment. What could we check more?

Comment: For what it's worth LevelDB was deprecated by ActiveMQ way back in November 2016. [This article](https://www.openlogic.com/blog/activemq-community-deprecates-leveldb-what-you-need-know) does a good job of summarizing the situation. Given this I'm not sure how much help you're going to find.

Answer (score 1):

The LevelDB store in ActiveMQ has been deprecated for a couple years now and has seen no community support or maintenance.  Likely you've run into a latent bug in the implementation which will not get fixed most likely as LevelDB will likely be removed completely in 5.17.0 release.  I'd suggest moving to the KahaDB store or looking into ActiveMQ Artemis if you need replication and HA.